# "Did you watch this movie?" or "Have you watched this movie?"

Tags: questions, present-perfect, past-simple

What is the difference between

> Did you watch this movie?

and

> Have you watched this movie?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The two common wordings are *did you watch* and *have you seen*.

*Did you watch* generally takes a time frame or some other constraint. For example:

> Did you watch Avengers last night?
>
> Did you watch Tron with Billy last week?
>
> Did you watch Jurassic Park before Jurassic Park II came out?

In contrast, *have you seen* asks if you have *ever* watched the given movie, at any point.

> Have you seen Fright Night?

Comment: This ignores an actual phrase that the OP asks about. *Have you watched this movie?* is a perfectly good and useful sentence. Maybe this was the style of answer in 2013,but not anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the subtle difference between the tenses, usage in casual speech is a matter of style. Usage of perfect tenses is more common in England than in the US, and may be more common in certain areas or age groups than in others.

A nice summary can be found [here](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_present-perfect_u.htm).

Comment: It's good practice to include the important portions of linked content in an answer, as if the linked website goes down the information will be lost.

Answer (score -2):

Have you seen this movie...indicates -  Have is in this time frame
Did you see that movie....indicates - Did was in that past time frame

Using Have means you are asking a question for something you want. Time, money, watched
and so on.

Using Did is a formal question where you need just a good answer.