# didn't work/ hasn't worked

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I want to print something but the printer does not work

Should I say after some attempts : why it didn't work? or what it has not worked?

To me there are the same and have the same meaning but the past simple sound better and are more likely to be used.

Is it true?

Comment: Neither is correct in the form you provided.

Comment: You can ask  "Why hasn't it worked?", "Why didn't it work?" or, especially if you are still trying, "Why isn't it working?" To ask a question we say **isn't it**, **hasn't it** or **didn't it**. To make a statement we say **it isn't**, **it hasn't** or **it didn't**.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Does your first questions mean somehow the same? (Why hasn't... Why didn't...)

Comment: @Meedfried If the printer **does** nothing you might ask, "Why doesn't it work?" If the printer **did** nothing you might ask, "Why didn't it work?" We would use "Why hasn't it worked?", as Kate Bunting says, when you discover the ink is smudged, or it's the wrong colour, or when  it has printed the wrong text or used the wrong font.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian, I do not really see the point, when we have to use the PP "It has not worked". Is it because, we see the result in the present?

Comment: @Meedfried The difference in subtle. There are times when we might say it didn't OR it hasn't. I didn't OR I haven't. In the evening, in the UK we might ask, 'Have you eaten yet?' In the US they might ask, 'Did you eat yet?' It seems to me 'Have you' refers to the _recent_ past; 'Did you' to either the recent **or** the _not_ recent past. 'I haven't eaten' suggests you haven't _yet_; 'I didn't eat' suggests you chose not to eat. If a friend points to the sky and says, "A shooting star!" You must say, "I didn't see it". "I haven't seen it" would suggest you haven't seen it _yet_. But it's gone!

Comment: @Meedfried If a teacher asks, "Where is your homework?" and you reply, "I haven't done it," then perhaps you were interrupted and you _might_ do it sometime. "I didn't do it" suggests you chose not to do it and you won't do it. "It hasn't worked" suggests it might still work: perhaps you could try again. "It didn't work" suggests you have given up. "It hasn't worked" suggests "It hasn't worked _yet_".

Comment: Thank you, I understand, the present perfect means that the action is somehow not finished in the present or only relevant. But for a foreigner, it must be hard to think that in real time or need a lot of practise before doing no mistake. But, anyway, even if there is a mistake it should be understandable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Did you watch this movie?" or "Have you watched this movie?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11723/did-you-watch-this-movie-or-have-you-watched-this-movie)

Answer (score 1):

If the printer *doesn't work*, probably nothing happens when you switch it on/click on 'Print'.

If you find that it *hasn't worked,* you have probably got a print, but find that the ink is smudged or it has printed the wrong text.